# jquery undefined error for simple ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, canvasjs

I have included jquery, then all ui js files as few thread suggested that this error is due to dependency. Using canvasjs to draw graph when users upload photos.

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined
```

Bootstrap html with all required dependencies. I think some loop issue or variable is not getting passed correctly, but console.log shows valid json as per required data points of canvasjs.if those points are directly embedded in that data points graph is generated without any error or issue.

I tried to update function of canvasjs also but does not work and I think that is not required as these data are passed with success so blank data is not being passed. I have doubt that for loop is the culprit, but don't know how and why

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {

        $('#upload-form2').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
               var sthtml;              
                var html = '',
                    downlo;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    z = i + 1;
                    downlo = data[i];
                    html += '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + z + '</td></tr>';
                sthtml += downlo.stchart;

                }

// canvas graph starts here

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {     
      theme:"theme2",
      title:{
        text: "Game of Thrones, Viewers of the first airing on HBO"
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "spline",        
       dataPoints: [sthtml]
// this is the culprit dont know why but console.log shows correct canvasjs.min.js:103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined
    //         dataPoints: [{ x: 3, y: 150 },{ x: 2, y: 14}]     
 //gives no error however my console.log output is exactly same in last line of this script 
 },
      {        
        type: "spline", 
       dataPoints: [{ x: 1, y: 450 },{ x: 2, y: 414}] 
      } 
      ],
    });
chart.render();

// canvas graph ends here

//console.log(sthtml);
            }
        })
    })();
});
```

Comment: what data it has sthtml ???

Comment: @Dinesh response json data is { x: 1, y: 450 },{ x: 2, y: 414} similar type

Comment: @Dinesh  
thanks for answer .i think this is the correct way as i am not getting error now but the json is getting meshed up so graph is not showing. the console log shows data like this ["{ x: 3, y: 33.6 },", "{ x: 4, y: 62.2 },", "{ x: 5, y: 121.2 },", "", x: 0] i dont know how ", " are coming my json output is simply { x: 3, y: 33.6 }like that. i have changed my json and removed, so comma will be added by jquery but how i can avoid [ and "

Comment: Do you control over server side code? the json format is quite wrong.

Comment: @Dinesh i control server side code but that is as per requirement of canvasjs data format

Comment: @Dinesh i will accept this answer as output by console.log adds array [ and quotes but alert shows exactly what i want however graph is still not being rendered. :( thanks for ur  help

Comment: what is your backend? can you please print json data at server side and check once ?

Comment: @Dinesh i have printed json data and even alert is giving correct format. mostly it is issue with console.log which adds [ and "

Comment: ok any errors in browser console?

Comment: @Dinesh even i cant add alert inside graph part it gives red error in dremaweaver

Comment: i can't see image

Comment: @Dinesh which image ?? plz scroll little u can see one graph which is coming as we have already given some value in first dataset for testing purpose, second will come from our code which we are trying but only one line is coming http://prntscr.com/fo9ow0

Comment: way2enjoy.com/compress-jpeg herer

Comment: @Dinesh we have to upload few images then the output will come

Comment: ok now i can tell you what is the problem after debugging your app. you are getting response as a string that is `"stchart":"{ x: 3, y: 95.2 }"` like this. this is wrong way of sending data from server. try to send as json from server. your are creating { x: 3, y: 95.2 } this as a string why? you can give this as a object and send as it is

Comment: Your response should be like this "stchart":{ "x": 3, "y": 95.2 }

Comment: @dinesh thanks for everything. u have helped maximum possible, iwill update once i get the result. thanks angel dinesh

Comment: all the best. feel free to ask if any questions. thanks

Comment: @Dinesh its working thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sthtml should be array type. you have used concatenation operation for sthtml that will convert sthtml to string. you need to use array push operation to push.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {

        $('#upload-form2').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
               var sthtml=[];// sthhtml is array              
                var html = '',
                    downlo;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    z = i + 1;
                    downlo = data[i];
                    html += '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + z + '</td></tr>';
                sthtml.push(downlo.stchart); // use push to push objects

                }

// canvas graph starts here

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {     
      theme:"theme2",
      title:{
        text: "Game of Thrones, Viewers of the first airing on HBO"
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "spline",        
       dataPoints: sthtml
// this is the culprit dont know why but console.log shows correct canvasjs.min.js:103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined
    //         dataPoints: [{ x: 3, y: 150 },{ x: 2, y: 14}]     
 //gives no error however my console.log output is exactly same in last line of this script 
 },
      {        
        type: "spline", 
       dataPoints: [{ x: 1, y: 450 },{ x: 2, y: 414}] 
      } 
      ],
    });
chart.render();

// canvas graph ends here

//console.log(sthtml);
            }
        })
    })();
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer .i think this is the correct way as i am not getting error now but the json is getting meshed up so graph is not showing. the console log shows data like this ["{ x: 3, y: 33.6 },", "{ x: 4, y: 62.2 },", "{ x: 5, y: 121.2 },", "", x: 0]   i dont know how ", " are coming my json output is simply { x: 3, y: 33.6 }like that